# Conversión extraña entre String y Double o Float

Tags: android, string, double, float

Estoy creando una app en donde le agregué en una pantalla una calculadora. Resulta que en mi código pongo que si hay un punto en lo que ingresa el usuario lo convierta de String a Double (utilizando un EditText) y si no lo tiene lo convierta de String a Integer.

Me di cuenta que todo va bien hasta que se hace la conversión, el número que ingreso es '123456789.1' y cuando lo convierto a Double pasa a ser '1.23456792E8'.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Este es el pedazo de código que utilizo para verificar el punto y hacer la conversion:

```
if (calculadora_input.getText().toString().contains(".") | resultado_textView.getText().toString().contains(".")){
                            double doble1 = Double.parseDouble(texto1);
                            double doble2 = Double.parseDouble(calculadora_input.getText().toString());
                            double resultdoble = doble1 + doble2;
                            resultado_textView.setText("" + resultdoble);
                            calculadora_input.setText("");
                        } else {
                            num1 = Integer.parseInt(texto1);
                            num2 = Integer.parseInt(calculadora_input.getText().toString());
                            resultSuma = num1 + num2;
                            resultado_textView.setText("" + resultSuma);
                            calculadora_input.setText("");
                        }
```

También intenté usando Float y sucede lo mismo.

Comment: Use BigDecimal, !double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

me parece que el valor de double si es correcto, solo que la notación científica exponencial es utilizada para simplificar el número. Puedes realizar operaciones con el número, pero si lo que quieres es mostrar el numero deberías utilizar `String.format()`. Agrego el siguiente ejemplo.

```
double dd = Double.parseDouble("123456789.1");

System.out.println(String.format("%.0f",dd));
System.out.println(String.format("%.2f",dd));
System.out.println(String.format("%.12f",dd));
```

Y el resultado de la consola es la siguiente:

```
123456789
123456789,10
123456789,100000000000
```

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: Muchas gracias. Por el momento desistí de la calculadora ya que de la nada los botones cambiaban su tamaño (solo su altura), lo dejaré para otra versión, pero probaré tu solución a ver qué tal me va. Nuevamente gracias por responder.